# How do I handle Kafka KStream unexpected state?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka stream that is set up as follows:

1. A message comes in on topic A with state "created"
2. A remote REST endpoint is called to notify that the message was received
3. The message is then transformed (state is set to "notified") and sent
   back out on topic A

I know how to set this up for the happy path (REST endpoint returns HTTP 2xx).  My question is: if my endpoint returns 400, how do I configure my kstream to handle that and not emit a message?

Here's my KSteam config:

```
    final KStream<String, Message> stream = streamsBuilder.stream(topic,
            Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), messageJsonSerde));
    stream
            .filter((key, value) -> MessageType.CASE_MATCHED.equals(
                    value.getEventType()))
            .mapValues(notifierService::handleNotification) // calls REST endpoint
            .to(topic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), messageJsonSerde));
    return stream;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the simplest way would be, to add another `filter` after the `mapValue` that drops messages that got not successfully processed.

You could change the first `mapValue` to add this information to the record such that the `filter` can access it. Additionally, you can do a second `mapValue` after the second `filter` to remove this additional `success` flag to write an unmodified message back to Kafka.

Of course, this won't reprocess any failed message but only filter out failed messages from the output.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  Not exactly what I was looking for but it'll do.